# Get data from remote php file

Tags: php, html

I have a remote php file with some parameters in the URL. This file shows PHARMACIES in COUNTRY selected, for example:

http://www.mydomanin.com/data/pharmacy/get_pharmacy.php?state=THE_STATE&country=THE_COUNTRY

And the server displays a HTML table with below data in 4 rows, based on the current date.

STATE: States (Same states)
PHARMACY: The name of the pharmacy
ADDRESS: The address of the pharmacy
MAP: Google Map

I only need to display PHARMACY and ADDRESS. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Parse the incoming data, or better yet, tell whoever wrote the remote script to allow you to specify columns to return.

Comment: what is the php output? JSON?

Comment: You want to change the content of somebody else's site? Are you trying to break the internets? ;)

Comment: Apparently: XML. Unfortunately I have no access to that file directly.

Comment: because you don't have posted an example of the page is difficult, but maybe you can use the regular expression to grab it if it's html or try to get your data loding the file and parse it with simpleXml http://hk1.php.net/simplexml

Comment: I'd look into the `DOMDocument()` class. This has a method named [`loadHTMLFile`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) which would then let you use the DOM to loop over the table and read out the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact answer as there was not enough detail in the question and I'm not going to write it all for you but the following example of parsing a HTML table using the DOMDocument PHP class should give you a good idea of a possible way of tackling this problem.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLfile( "/path/to/file" );
//$doc->loadHTML("<html><body><table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr></table></body></html>");

$tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName("table");

foreach( $tables as $table ) {
    $rows = $table->childNodes;
    foreach( $rows as $row ) {
        if( $row->nodeName == "tr" ) {
            $columns = $row->childNodes;
            foreach( $columns as $column ) {
                if( $column->nodeName == "td" ) {
                    // $column->nodeValue
                    print_r( $column );
                    echo "<br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**EDIT:** The `/path/to/file` can also be a URL rather then a local file.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt get your question properly, but as far as i understand, you hit the url which displays a html page with some table. If you have data in the table, you can get the html using CURL library in PHP and then parse it with the answer above!!

Comment: You shouldn't even need to use cURL unless you choose to. The file path can be a URL as with most PHP file opening functions. :)